# printing dynamic value of js file inside html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on dynamic web application. I'm getting the response back from java spring controller and displaying the results in the html page.
I have many fields(like id, spread%,CreatedDate,Opinion,comments...) on the webpage. When printing the values directly on the webpage, date is printed as some number(1485882060000) on the webpage. So i am converting it to a date object in the javascript file using `new Date(val)` as shown below.

```
MyService.getResults(id).then(
    function(response) {
        $scope.results = response;
        angular.forEach($scope.results,function(value,key){
            var startDateRange = new Date(value.startDate);/*Want to print this value in place of {{data.startDate}} in results.html*/
            var endDateRange = new Date(value.endDate);/*Want to print this value in place of {{data.endDate}} in results.html*/
     
        });
    },
    function(errResponse){
        console.error('Error in getResults');
    });
```

results.html

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:5%;">ID</th>
            <th style="width:5%;">Spread%</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">StartDate</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">EndDate</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Opinion</th>
            <th style="width:20%;">comments</th>
       </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in results
            <td >{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.spread}}</td>
            <td>{{data.startDate}}</td> /*how to print startDateRange value from javascript file*/
            <td>{{data.EndDate}}</td> /*how to print endDateRange value from javascript file*/
            <td>{{data.Opinion}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Comments}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Please advice how to print the JavaScript variable values in html dynamically.
Currently with the above code, I'm getting the date fields printed in html page as mentioned below.

> In Place of {{data.startDate}} value shown is : 1485882060000 .
>
> In place of {{data.endDate}} value shown is :  1490298780000

Instead, I want to print the modified javascript variable values startDateRange and endDateRange in the iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you want to convert epoch timestamp(milliseconds since 1st Jan, 1970) to date. You can use angular's date filter(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to convert this value to a particular date format.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in results
            <td >{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.spread}}</td>
            <td>{{data.startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
            <td>{{data.EndDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Opinion}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Comments}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return the dates as strings, you can then convert them to dates in the JS code. Javascript does not understand dates in the current format.

Comment: now I can able to convert the date to date format in js file using var startDateRange  = new Date(value.startDate); My questions is how can I print dynamic js file value startDateRange  inside html file. Please read my question.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is it currently printing and what do you want it to print?

Comment: I want to print the javascript variables startDateRange , endDateRange values in results.html in place of {{data.startDate}} and {{data.endDate}}

Comment: As I asked, what is currently being displayed and what is the intended result of the display